# lambda-calculus in C: Booleans and NOT operator

Tags: c, lambda-calculus

I wanted to give implementations in different programming languages of the lambda-calculus construction of the booleans and the NOT operator.

These are:

```
TRUE = lx.ly. x
FALSE = lx.ly. y
NOT = lx. x FALSE TRUE
```

It's trivial to do in Javascript and Python say, like

```
var TRUE = function(x,y){ return x;} 
var FALSE = function(x,y){ return y;}
var NOT = function(b){ return b(FALSE,TRUE) ; }
```

but I can't figure out how to do it in C.

The naive idea of implementing something like this

```
lambda true(lambda x, lambda y){ return x ; }
lambda false(lambda x, lambda y){ return x ; }

lambda not(lambda (b)(lambda, lambda) ){ return b(false,true) ;}
```

doesn't seem possible in C, as `typedef` doesn't allow a recursive definition

```
typedef void (*lambda)(lambda,lambda) ;not valid in C
```

Is there a way to do it in C? and is there a way to do it that is meaningful to use as an educational example? That is, if the syntax starts getting to cumbersome it ends up defeating its purpose...

Finally, if C ends up being too limited in any way, an answer in C++ would also work for me, albeit with the same "complexity" constraint

I may be expecting too much of C.

EDIT:
Following the suggestion by Tom in the comments, the following definitions do compile

```
typedef void *(*bol)() ;

bol true(bol x, bol y){ return x ; }
bol false(bol x, bol y){ return x ; }

bol not(bol b ){ return b(false,true) ;}



int main(){
 bol p = not((bol)true);

 return 0;
}
```

EDIT2: This, however, is not strictly conforming as Tom and others have pointed out.

Furthermore, as @Antti Haapala, and @n.m point out, this may be asking too much of C.

At this point I'm skeptical that there could be a simple enough implementation in C++.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159410/discussion-on-question-by-masl-lambda-calculus-in-c-booleans-and-not-operator).

Comment: @Andy Now that's a bad timing...because of late. The discussion was long over. This thread is dead now without the enlighting comments from Tom, n.m. and Antti. This helps nobody.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to write a mini-interpreter that would understand lambda-code?

Comment: @MASL if there were comments of lasting value here or later in chat they should be moved into an (existing) answer so 1) they're summarised and searchable unlike comments and 2) can be voted on and 3) less liable to deletion and more prominently accessible.

Comment: @JonClements So what's the point of comments then? None of the comments left, this one included, are really of much a value for anyone landing here, let alone of a lasting one. Maybe stackoverflow should automatically move all comments  to a trash after a few hours...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I know in C to declare recursive declarations is by using struct, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

typedef struct LAMBDA {
    struct LAMBDA * (*function)(struct LAMBDA *, ...);
} *lambda;

lambda trueFunction(lambda x, ...) {return x;}
lambda true = &(struct LAMBDA) {.function = trueFunction};

lambda falseFunction(lambda x, ...) {va_list argp; va_start(argp, x); lambda y = va_arg(argp, lambda); va_end(argp); return y;}
lambda false = &(struct LAMBDA) {.function = falseFunction};

lambda notFunction(lambda b, ...) {return b->function(false, true);}
lambda not = &(struct LAMBDA) {.function = notFunction};

int main() {
    lambda p1 = not->function(true);
    lambda p2 = not->function(false);
    printf("%p %p %p %p", true, p1, false, p2);
    return 0;
}
```

Its hard for me to judge whether such syntax is too cumbersome or not, obviously less clear than dynamic languages.

Comment: Nice. This is the other alternative Tom suggested. Yes, I think it's difficult to make a point about Lambda calculus using this example as the syntax starts getting in the way, but it deserves a +1 for showing such a use of struct in this case. One note: That printf requires the arguments to be cast into ```void *``` to make the code strictly compliant (gcc -pedantic).